# Reference for differential topology that uses the differential forms framework

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, differential-forms

I came across [Hirsch's differential topology](http://people.dm.unipi.it/benedett/HIRSCH.pdf) and I really like the content of the book. However I cannot find a reference book with similar content (especially the Morse theory part) and differential forms.

Can anyone suggest a reference for differential topology that uses the framework of differential forms?

My background at the moment is Tu's An Introduction to Smooth manifolds, and the first four chapters of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, but I'd like a digression in differential topology that potentially uses differential forms.